# Redirecting in asp.net 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, redirect, actionresult

I am still learning to work with asp.net and I am trying to redirect to an Edit action in a controller from another controller, but I can’t find out how to make it work.
this is what I have

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Worker");
```

or

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Worker", 25);
```

I need it to be something like this:
http://localhost:xxxxx/Worker/Edit/25

Comment: You should describe what's not working about your approach, not just say what you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Worker", new { id = 25});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the ***route value parameters*** as `Route value` Object using the `new` Keyword...as

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Worker", new { id = 25});
```

And if you want to *add multiple values* you can go like adding the values separated by a ***comma*** `,`

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Worker", new { id = 25,name ="tushar"});
```

Or you can create a `RouteValueDictionary` , add the items and send the ***object*** of it at once as

```
RouteValueDictionary _routValueDict = new RouteValueDictionary();
_routValueDict.Add("param1", param1);
_routValueDict.Add("param2", param2);
```

No pass the ***object*** like :

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Worker", _routValueDict );
```